# Get values of dynamically created input elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created dynamic `input` elements using the JavaScript below:

```
while(count<n-2){
  if(dataArray[count+1]=='String')
    var txt = "Argument:"+(count+1)+", Prefix: <input type=\"text\" name=\"prefix[]\">, Default value: <input type=\"text\" name=\"defaultval[]\" id=\"defaultval[]\"> <br>"; 
  else if(dataArray[count+1]=='File')
      var txt = "Argument:"+(count+1)+", Prefix: <input type=\"text\" name=\"prefix[]\">, Default file: <input type=\"file\" name=\"fileToUpload[]\" id=\"fileToUpload[]\"> <br>"; 

      $("#dynamic_element").append(txt);
  count++;
}
```

How to get values of the created `inputs` using jQuery?

I mean something like this inside a function:

```
function myFunc(){
    var x0 = $('#defaultval[0]').val();
    var y0= $('#fileToUpload[0]').val();
}
```

Comment: In many ways, but how do you want to get the values? Click, right inside your function, on submit, on blurr...

Comment: @Lixus I have updated my post hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Square parentheses aren't valid characters for ids. Either remove them or, instead, use:

```
var x0 = $('input[id="defaultval[0]"]').val();
var y0 = $('input[id="fileToUpload[0]"]').val();
```

Working example:

```js
var x0 = $('input[id="defaultval[0]"]').val();
var y0 = $('input[id="fileToUpload[0]"]').val();

$('#example1').text('value of "defaultval[0]": ' + x0);
$('#example2').text('value of "fileToUpload[0]": ' + y0);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="defaultval[0]" name="defaultval[0]" value="0">
<input type="text" id="fileToUpload[0]" name="fileToUpload[0]" value="1">
<br>
<span id="example1"></span>
<br>
<span id="example2"></span>
```

Comment: Your example seems ignores that the elements are dynamically created. I tried your solution in my code but it always gives `undefined` values.

Comment: It's because we don't have all of your code. We don't know which ones you want to select and when, if you have an index (it seems so) and also in the code you posted that creates the inputs you didn't put any number inside the square parentheses.